# Get current page, data pager?

Tags: asp.net

I have this datapager and I want to get the current page. I checked out the properties of about everything and the MSDN documentation and I still did not find anything useful to get the current page. Can anyone help?

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="ListView1" PageSize="10">

<Fields>

<asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" FirstPageText="<<" PreviousPageText="<" ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowNextPageButton="false" />

<asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="3" />

<asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Link" LastPageText=">>" NextPageText=">" ShowLastPageButton="true" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" />

</Fields>

</asp:DataPager>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a SharePoint question, however here is the answer:

That data isn't actual stored as part of the Data Pager control.  It is done with the ListView or GridView. (See [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125144848/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021308-1.aspx) for some more information on that).

Basically you can use the StartRowIndex property of the ListView/GridView to determine where you are.  You may want to tweak the math a bit for your needs, but if you divide the StartRowIndex by the page size and then either round up to one, if less than one, or round down to the nearest whole number, you should end up with the page you are on.